# map.setCenter undefined

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using GoogleMaps and want to centre it when the orientation changes, but when I call

```
map.setCenter({...})
```

I'm receiving an undefined error for setCenter.

Here's my code:

```
let GoogleMap = {
  lat : "",
  lng : "",
  map : {},
  marker : {},
  point : {},

  init() {
    return this
  },

  create(lat, lng) {
    this.lat = lat
    this.lng = lng
    this.point = {lat: lat,lng: lng};

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: this.point,
      zoom: 17
    });

    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      position: this.point
    });

    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.doOnOrientationChange);
  },

  doOnOrientationChange() {
    this.map.setCenter({lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng})
  }
}

export default GoogleMap
```

Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

And I grab the google maps api from: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=geometry,places

Any ideas?

Comment: are you providing and values for lat and lng, if you provided all the code might be easier to debug

Comment: Please visit this solution for you problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537225/map-setcenter-function-is-not-working-properly

Comment: Jason, the lat/lng values passed in to the create function are just Floats, the map displays fine, the problem I'm having is with using the setCenter method on the map object in the doOreientationChange function - when the orientation changes.

Comment: Thanks NikuNj, but your answer doesn't address my problem, namely; map.setCenter = undefined. The map is displayed fine, exactly as it should be, my issue is with the setCenter function, and why it doesn't exist on my map object.

Comment: I suspect that `this` isn't what you expect inside the orientation event handler function.

Comment: geocodezip - yes you are right, thanks. Fixed using the bind method: window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.orientationChange.bind(this));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to geocodezip, the issue was scoping, and this wasn't in the correct scope in the orientation event handler.

The fix was to use the bind method

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.orientationChange.bind(this));
```

Full working code:

```
let GoogleMap = {
  lat : "",
  lng : "",
  map : {},
  marker : {},
  point : {},

  init() {
    return this
  },

  create(lat, lng) {
    this.lat = lat
    this.lng = lng
    this.point = {lat: lat,lng: lng};

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: this.point,
      zoom: 17
    });

    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      position: this.point
    });

    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.orientationChange.bind(this));
  },

  orientationChange() {
    this.map.setCenter({lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng})
  }
}

export default GoogleMap
```

The map now centres itself as expected when the orientation changes.